# Switching Facebook API from v 5 to v 6

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I have this code that was using Facebook C# API v5 and was running on a AJAX call to figure out if user is authenticated:

```
// Make sure user is logged into Facebook and authroized this application
if (!FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() ||
!FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized(new[] { "email" }))
{
    result.ResultCode = BasicResultCode.NotAuthorized;
    return result;
}

var fbuid = FacebookWebContext.Current.UserId;
```

In v6, Facebook.Web namespace doesn't exist and FacebookWebContext is nowhere to be found. What do I use instead for the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you or not, but as far as I understand, Facebook removed these features from the c# sdk because they wanted to change the structure of some Facebook cookies. By removing FacebookWebContext they/you don't risk running into issues where the cookie structure might have changed and things are no longer compatible.

Instead, I think you should try to do your authentication through the [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Try using 
[FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and/or
[FB.getAuthResponse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/)

Answer (score 0):

The FacebookWebContext is no longer available. This was already marked in version 5 has deprecated. Check your warning screen in Visual Studio when you do a Rebuild All on your solution.

Now you have to use FacebookClient() from the Facebook namespace.

You then have to check for a FacebookOAuthException that can have multiple results. You can find the documentation of the FacebookOAuthException on https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Facebook.Web is no longer there in v6, as well as FacebookWebClient class.

Comment: Sorry Andrey, you where right. I was looking in my old branche. Im also converting from 5 to 6. Tonight there was a new post of the makers of the SDK. Maybe that can help you. http://blog.ntotten.com/2012/07/23/facebook-apps-and-windows-azure-web-sites-part-1-getting-started/

Comment: Ok, let's do this: I remove "-1" and you delete this incorrect answer - win-win :)

Comment: Well, I don't know if you saw it but I edited my answer. If that doesn't work I will delete my answer ;)